# Template selector and creation of ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an ItemsControl with ItemTemplateSelector and for some Template I need to create a ViewModel (I can use a ViewModelLocator if needed) with a parameter. How can I do it ?  Is using a converter the only way ?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridTemplate">
        <Control:MyView DataContext="???CreateViewModelWithParameter" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectDataProvider, and then bind the Data Context.

For clarity the sample below do it for a button. Do the same for your button control. You'll end up with a Window and a Button that has a text 'Joe'.

View Model:

```
public class MyVM
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public MyVm( string n ) {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:so="clr-namespace:SO"
    Width="300" Height="200"
    x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    Title="SO Sample"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="datasrc" ObjectType="{x:Type so:MyVm}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <clr:String>Joe</clr:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>            
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=datasrc}}" Content="{Binding Path=name}" />
</Window>
```